# position sticky Safari

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, safari

При наличии обычного div и при `position: -webkit-sticky;` все отлично на сафари работает, но когда div кидается в div ничего не работает, прошу помощи

```
<div class="w">
  <div class="sticky">321</div>
</div>
<div id = 'k' class="absd"></div>

div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  top: 20px;
}
div.absd {
  background: blue;
  height: 2120px;
}
```

Comment: какой еще sticky????

Comment: @Demon__ANT, position: -webkit-sticky

Comment: впервые слышу о стике

Comment: Ну да, sticky работает строго в пределах внешнего контейнера. Вы не указали внешнему контейнеру размеры, поэтому контейнер принимает размеры своего содержимого, поэтому и sticky работать тупо негде. Увеличьте высоту у `<div class="w">` и всё заработает

Comment: Или же просто повесьте position:sticky на этот самый `<div class="w">`

Comment: @andreymal, благодарю. А можно сделать как-то иначе, чтоб было стики не только в пределах родительского дива, а в пределах всего окна?
Находил где люди используют display, но у меня не заработало =(

Comment: Очевидно, внешним контейнером должно стать всё окно, соответственно не заворачивайте sticky ни в какой див. Откуда у вас необходимость заворачивать?

Comment: @andreymal, задание такое, имеется еще и прародительский div. Имеются какие-то мысли как это реализовать?

Comment: @LooneyZ как я уже говорил, sticky работает в пределах внешнего контейнера, следовательно — или избавляйтесь от дивов, или растягивайте див на всё окно любым доступным вам способом

Comment: Хотя я тут нашёл ещё один финт ушами — `.w {display: inline;}` но это лютый костыль и пожалуйста *не надо* так делать

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за ответ, но если бы этот костыль у меня еще работал) Я в замешательстве

Comment: Ну в приведённом вами примере этот костыль работает. Чем-то более дельным помочь вряд ли получится, потому что непонятно, зачем вам эти дивы вообще нужны

Comment: @adreymal, в хроме работает, но в сафари нет, в этом то вся и проблема